# Add Mouse Event to all Child Elements in DIv

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    $(window).mousedown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {

            // left click
            case 1:
                e.preventDefault()
                $(e.target).css("border", "2px solid red");
                break;

            // Middle  click
            case 2:
                e.preventDefault()
                $(e.target).css("border", "");
                break;
        }
    });
```

The following code works great.
Whenever I click on any elements it would create a red box and when I click the middle button from the mouse
it removes the red box.

BUT:
what i want is I want the same functionality but want to apply to particular div elements only.

```
  <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 1px; overflow-y: scroll; height: 450px;" >
                    <div id="webappcontents">
                        {{{this.html}}}
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to add mouse click events on
div `#webappcontents`. Hhow can I achieve this?
This way all contents inside `#webappcontents` is clickable and creates red box.

Any help is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code: `$(window).mousedown(function(e) {` is catching any mouse click on the page
To specify the `webappcontents` div change that to

```
$('#webappcontents').mousedown(function(e) {
```

though you might want to only make certain elements that way, like all  with the class='clickable' inside that container...

```
$('#webappcontents div.clickable').mousedown(function(e) {
   // now you can access the element to modify with $(this)
   // $(this).addClass('clicked')
```

Also, make sure this function registers after page load.. One way is using the jQuery `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#webappcontents').mousedown(function(e) {
        // do stuff
   })
});
```

Comment: Hello i want to make all items clickable inside that div
following code didnt work     $("#webappcontents div").mousedown(function(e) {

Comment: `$('#webappcontents').mousedown(function(e) {` adds a single click element to the container and you'll be able to access the exact clicked object with `e.target`. My second suggestion was only to make your code more legible - where at a glance you know that the intended objects are all `div.clickable` and the transformation is done using a `css class` rather than editing the style directly.

Comment: Hello Thanks for prompt reply seems like its not working     $("#webappcontents").mousedown(function(e) {
i tried adding alert object when i click on elements under that div its not firing up event

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah Most likely you have your javascript above your HTML. So `$("#webappcontents").mousedown` is trying to register before the HTML exists. I will modify my answer with `$(document).ready(`

Comment: God bless thanks for all help :D cheer you made my Sunday

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah  You're welcome. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it helped solve your issue.

Comment: roger that :D you have a nice day